# Convert json from URL to CSV for D3.js

Tags: php, json, csv, d3.js

I am reading in json from a web API which json encodes data from a mysql database. The URL from the web API returns json as such:

```
{"result":[{"name":"joe","how_many":"5"},{"name":"chris","how_many":"10"},{"name":"steven","how_many":"5"},{"name":"melissa","how_many":"2"}]}
```

I am working with a D3.js graph that requires a CSV file format as such:

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data){
// do D3 stuff here 
}
```

I am trying to convert the json response from the web API into something that the CSV-dependent D3 graph can interpret.  Does the CSV need to be a file on the server and therefore I must convert the JSON response to a CSV file using say some PHP server side script? Or would it make more sense to read in the JSON as a string object in javascript...then convert that to a 'CSV String(?)' and allow D3 to read the newly created CSV String?

I can use AJAX to read in the JSON from the url and get the JSON using get.JSON... but how can I then make this available as CSV format for D3?

Comment: What kind of graph do you want to make? I guess you don't need to convert it to CSV at all. Just restructure your object.

Comment: D3 doesn't require CSV or any other kind of data format. As long as you can get your data into the required structure, you're fine.

Comment: The graph is this one http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Ditto what the other 2 comments said. Also, keep in mind that `data` — as in `d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data){` — is also json object, since d3 parses the csv into json form.

Comment: You probably just want `d3.json('some/url.json', function(error, json) { var data = json.result; });`, which will make `data` an array of objects in the format expected by the example you're using.

Comment: I tried that...but it doesn't work. One problem is that D3 wants a json file...not the response from a url.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you want to do.

Comment: So I was able to save the mysql to a csv file on the server using this solution http://bit.ly/1zlFB7F.  Works great. Thank you.

Comment: you can just insert a variable in place of the file path..